# sql declare string and use in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @Symb varchar
SET @Symb = 'Lara'
SELECT     Names
FROM         Cricket
where Names like '@Symb%'
```

I need all the names starting with 'Lara'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Symb varchar(10)
SET @Symb = 'Lara'
SELECT     Names
FROM         Cricket
WHERE Names LIKE @Symb + '%'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT     Names
FROM         Cricket
where Symbol like @Symb+'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the % when you set your variable :

```
SET @Symb = 'Lara%'
```

or use a CONCAT function to add your % symbol to your variable.

Else, that way you, you'll be looking for every names starting by '@Symb'

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Symb varchar(10)
SELECT @Symb = 'Lara' + '%'
SELECT     Names
  FROM         Cricket
  WHERE Names like @Symb
```